Java SSLContext: Set truststore from a KeyStore-Object
I am trying a mTLS-socket with Java.
KeyStore ks = .....
KeyManagerFactory kmf = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance (KeyManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm ());
kmf.init (ks, pass.toCharArray ());
SSLContext ctx = SSLContext.getInstance ("TLS");
ctx.init (kmf.getKeyManagers (), null, null);
SSLSocketFactory sslsf = ctx.getSocketFactory ();

Thats all ok and working. I also need a trust store for the server/client-certificate.
My default trust-store of my OS is inside the file
/etc/ssl/certs/java/cacert.

If I want another file I can set it with
System.setProperty ("javax.net.ssl.trustStore", "/etc/ssl/certs/java/mycacerts");

Thats all fine too.
But I want to put a KeyStore-object (that I will create in front of the code above) as a truststore, not a file at the disk.
Similar to the KeyStore-object ks where I have mTLS cert/key inside.
Is it possible to do that somehow?

This is done in the fashion of
        SSLContext ctx = SSLContext.getInstance(protocol);
        ctx.init(keyManagers, trustManagers, null);

You're ignoring the second argument of init() in your code sample, you should just file it out. It is created in the same fashion as first argument keyManagers. The class used would be TrustManagerFactory.
See for example Apache Ignite's SSL context factory.
